# data frame usage in R

Tags: r

I have a `.csv` file which I have read into R as a dataframe (say df).
The first column is date in mm/dd/yyyy format. The second column is a double number. What I want to do is to create a new dataframe like:

```
df2<-data.frame(date=c(df[10,1],df[15,2]),num=c(111,222))
```

When I try to do this I get very messy df2. Most probably I am doing it wrong because I do not understand the data frame concept.

Whenever I try to do `df[10,1]`, the output is the 10th row and 1st column of `df`, including all the levels of column 1.

Comment: If you provide a small reproducible example, it would be of much help (to us as well).

Comment: You are probably seeing how factor variables are printed at the console ... and those levels are not really the values, but rather the vector of possible values. The line above those levels has the value of the df[10, 1] item.

Answer (score 2):

You can control how R will interpret the classes of data being read in by specifying a vector of column classes as an argument to `read.table` with `colClasses`. Otherwise R will use `type.convert` which will convert a character vector in a "logical" fashion, according to R's definition of logical. That obviously has some potential quirks to it if you aren't familiar with them.

You can also prevent R from creating a factor by specifying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as an argument in `read.table`, this is generally an easier option than specifying all of the `colClasses`.

You can format the date with `strptime()`. Taking all of this into consideration, I would recommend reading your data into R without turning character data into factors and then use `strptime` to format.

```
df <- read.csv("myFile.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#Convert time to proper time format
df$time <- strptime(df$time, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to type out stringsAsFactors=FALSE each time you read in / construct a data frame. you can at the outset specify

```
 options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```