# R: TwitteR collecting tweets

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, twitter-r

So i am having troubles in saving my tweets , when i collected them and applied sapply on them they appear in this form

```
 some_txt = sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText())


[1] "RT @JanoImLukesSlut: #HarryHas17MillionFollowParty\nâ™” RT\nâ™”Follow me\nâ™”Ask4follow back\nâ™”Follow ALL who RTs\nâ™”Gain\nâ™”Drink pepsi feel sexyyy\n#Stoâ€¦"               
 [2] "RT @abria_valerie: Pepsi is like crack to me. I gotta have it."                                                                                                                  
 [3] "@JLinn6 having to stop for dr. Pepper bc someone doesn't like Pepsi. #picky #spoiledbrat #watchoutonlylikesdr.'s"                                                                
 [4] "RT @cyberscott1975: The coca cola truck can bugger off! I want a Pepsi Max Xmas Truck!í ½íºš"                                                                                    
 [5] "í ½í²•í ½í²•í ½í²•Mmm That Spicy Chicken Sandwich And Fries And Pepsi From Wendy's Was A1í ½í²¦"                                                                                 
 [6] "@JatnnaP05 @Alexandergr_ @IannErnesto @WilberJE ENTRA dale a GALERIA luego vota por : attabeira https://t.co/hh0Q5tkHzx  #HelpMe"                                                
 [7] "RT @supersunnytime: wallowing in a sea of pop punk and self-hatred"                                                                                                              
 [8] "These bitches love soda Pepsi and Cola"                                                                                                                                          
 [9] "RT @Lmao: waiter: \"what drink would you like\" \nme: \"Ñ‚Ð½Ñ” Ð²â„“ÏƒÏƒâˆ‚ ÏƒÆ’ Ð¼Ñƒ Ñ”Î·Ñ”Ð¼Î¹Ñ”Ñ•\" \nwaiter: \nme: \nwaiter: \nme: \nwaiter: \nme: \nwaiter: \"is pepsi oâ€¦"

               .......................
```

However when i apply a write csv to it . and then read it back out it does not come back the same format

```
   write.csv(some_txt, file = file.choose(), row.names = TRUE, sep = ',', col.names = TRUE)
   some_txt = read.csv(file.choose(), row.names = 1, sep = ',')
```

it instead comes back as

```
x
1            RT @JanoImLukesSlut: #HarryHas17MillionFollowParty\nâ™” RT\nâ™”Follow me\nâ™”Ask4follow back\nâ™”Follow ALL who RTs\nâ™”Gain\nâ™”Drink pepsi feel sexyyy\n#Stoâ€¦
2                                                                                                               RT @abria_valerie: Pepsi is like crack to me. I gotta have it.
3                                                             @JLinn6 having to stop for dr. Pepper bc someone doesn't like Pepsi. #picky #spoiledbrat #watchoutonlylikesdr.'s
4                                                                                 RT @cyberscott1975: The coca cola truck can bugger off! I want a Pepsi Max Xmas Truck!í ½íºš
5                                                                              í ½í²•í ½í²•í ½í²•Mmm That Spicy Chicken Sandwich And Fries And Pepsi From Wendy's Was A1í ½í²¦
6                                             @JatnnaP05 @Alexandergr_ @IannErnesto @WilberJE ENTRA dale a GALERIA luego vota por : attabeira https://t.co/hh0Q5tkHzx  #HelpMe
7                                                                                                           RT @supersunnytime: wallowing in a sea of pop punk and self-hatred
8                                                                                                                                       These bitches love soda Pepsi and Cola
9  RT @Lmao: waiter: "what drink would you like" \nme: "Ñ‚Ð½Ñ” Ð²â„“ÏƒÏƒâˆ‚ ÏƒÆ’ Ð¼Ñƒ Ñ”Î·Ñ”Ð¼Î¹Ñ”Ñ•" \nwaiter: \nme: \nwaiter: \nme: \nwaiter: \nme: \nwaiter: "is pepsi oâ€¦

                                      ......
```

Any idea on how to give it back the same value ? Im using csv because i want to collect these tweets manually .

this is the str() example of the some_txt (it's 50 tweets thats why its 1:50 )

```
  chr [1:50] "@psychicpebble AMEN THANK YOU FOR NOT TALKING ABOUT THAT PEPSI SHIT." ...
```

Edit:

this is the str() example of the output after reading(example)

```
     'data.frame':  50 obs. of  1 variable:
     $ x: Factor w/ 43 levels "$39 = Jack'n'Coke, Vodka &amp; Pepsi, and a 24 oz.      Miller Lite. Fml.",..: 10 24 33 9 13 39 9 21 6 31 ...
```

New Update:
I tried your method thomas, it's not exactly what i wanted , cause in my original some_txt i could do this

```
  > some_txt[2]
   [1] "RT @Nada_7Q: #ØªØ§Ø¨Ø¹Ù†ÙŠ_Ø§ØªØ§Ø¨Ø¹Ùƒ\n@toomy48\n@m_alzuhair\n@alzheri33    \n@hallm77\n@tooomy48\n@RT_FAEF\n@Nada_7Qâ˜…â˜†â˜…â˜†\n@abosaef11\n@adoan3\n@Msolfje\n@Khalid_06â€¦"
  > some_txt[1]
  [1] "RT @CodeClue: 50 CL Pepsi is unnecessary tbh."
  > some_txt[3]
  [1] "I just ate all my Dad's very expensive cheese and it's supposed to be eaten slowly with a nice glass of red not a Pepsi Max"
```

After applying the stringAsFactor to the read.csv , it still prints out the same thing, however the str() type has changed slightly. But i would want the entire list to be chr[1:50] ,not just a single one .
Also it only has a single list element in it not like my original some_txt above.
I really hope someone can help me >.< this has been giving me a headache

Comment: Look into the `fileEncoding` argument to `write.csv`, described in detail at [`? file`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html).

Comment: Is there a fileEncoding which actually puts it back into that format?

Comment: Looking at this more carefully, the input and output don't look any different. What are the differences you're seeing?

Comment: I need it to become back a chr[1:50]
however when i read it back , and str() it , it gives back a 
example :
'data.frame': 50 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: Factor w/ 43 levels "$39 = Jack'n'Coke, Vodka &amp; Pepsi, and a 24 oz. Miller Lite. Fml.",..: 10 24 33 9 13 39 9 21 6 31 ...

Comment: In `read.csv` set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. The `str(some_txt[,1])` should match what you're going for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [data frame usage in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520747/data-frame-usage-in-r)

Comment: Updated my results above, didnt work out very well.

Comment: I'm not sure at what level you're having difficulty. How experienced are you with R? Your starting object is vector of character strings. The instructions I gave will help you to read the CSV into R as a dataframe, which is a different type of R object. If you extract the one column of that dataframe (using `some_txt[,1]`), the resulting object will be a character vector like your original object...

Comment: Thanks, Thomas for sticking with me >.<
i finally got what i wanted.
I'm quite inexperienced with R still , just around few weeks in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did to put it back into a list of its original form.

```
 for(i in 1:length(some_txt[,1])){
  some_txt1 = c(some_txt1,some_txt[,1][i])
 }
```

I just basically create a for loop and just loop them back into a list.